# Python, response and if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, response

I am writing a program that sends command codes to a serial device and gets a response from the device, then sends another command. I can send the commands perfectly, and even get a response. However, my if statement does not seem to acknowledge the responses.

Example:

```
response = sendCommand(beep)
if response == '0D6010100':
  print"Command beeped!"
```

Like I mentioned, I get a successful response code of 0D6010100, but the if statement doesn't acknowledge it. Any ideas?

I am working with Python 2.7 and using PySerial

UDPATE:

print type(response) gives me:  
print repr(response) gives me: '0D6010100\r\n'
I assume the \r\n at the end of the repr(response) has some kind hand in this issue?

Comment: Well, what does `print type(response), repr(response)` show?  Maybe the response isn't what you think it is.

Comment: is the return value a string or number ??

Comment: How is the response being provided?  Is it really a string, or is it a base2 number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trim the response first:

```
if response.rstrip() == '0D6020100':
   print 'beepity boop beep woohoo!'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  Though I will probably use .strip() inside the sendCommand to keep from adding it to all the lines that would need it.  Cheers!

Comment: You might use `rstrip('\r\n')` to be specific about what you strip.

Answer (score 2):

As you suspected, the `\r\n` at the end is the problem.  Do

```
response = sendCommand(beep).strip()
```

to strip whitespace from the ends of your string.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  I could only accept one answer, so I accepted the first one; though your implementation is what I used. In the end, as I mention above, I will probably use .strip() inside the sendCommand to keep from adding it over and over.  Cheers!

Comment: Note that this will trim from the left and the right - it may not be what you want. On my answer its `rstrip()` so it only trims on the right.